# Unable to perform any actions using CodedUI on Popup(.NET) based application

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

After launching browser I am unable to click (or perform any actions) on Popup based application (.NET).

**Please find the recorded Code for clicking "OK" button of Popup from where I am taking element properties for my below generic code :**

```
UIIPVPNRouterCreationWWindow.UIItemWindow11.UIIPVPNRouterCreationWClient.UIItemWindow.UIIPVPNRouterCreationDocument.UIOKButton;

**UIIPVPNRouterCreationWWindow:**

[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "12.0.31101.0")]
    public class UIIPVPNRouterCreationWWindow : BrowserWindow
    {

        public UIIPVPNRouterCreationWWindow()
        {
            #region Search Criteria
            this.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name] = "IPVPN Router Creation";
            this.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "Internet Explorer_TridentDlgFrame";
            this.WindowTitles.Add("IPVPN Router Creation");
            #endregion
        }

        public void LaunchUrl(System.Uri url)
        {
            this.CopyFrom(BrowserWindow.Launch(url));
        }

**UIItemWindow11:**   
[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "12.0.31101.0")]
    public class UIItemWindow11 : WinWindow
    {

        public UIItemWindow11(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
                base(searchLimitContainer)
        {
            #region Search Criteria
            this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "ThunderRT6UserControlDC";
            this.WindowTitles.Add("IPVPN Router Creation");
            #endregion
        }
**UIIPVPNRouterCreationWClient:**  
 [GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "12.0.31101.0")]
    public class UIIPVPNRouterCreationWClient : WinClient
    {

        public UIIPVPNRouterCreationWClient(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
                base(searchLimitContainer)
        {
            #region Search Criteria
            this.WindowTitles.Add("IPVPN Router Creation");
            #endregion
        }
**UIItemWindow:**
[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "12.0.31101.0")]
    public class UIItemWindow5 : WinWindow
    {

        public UIItemWindow5(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
                base(searchLimitContainer)
        {
            #region Search Criteria
            this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "ThunderRT6ComboBox";
            this.WindowTitles.Add("IPVPN Router Creation");
            #endregion
        }


**UIIPVPNRouterCreationDocument:**

[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "12.0.31101.0")]
    public class UIIPVPNRouterCreationDocument : HtmlDocument
    {

        public UIIPVPNRouterCreationDocument(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
                base(searchLimitContainer)
        {
            #region Search Criteria
            this.SearchProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.Id] = null;
            this.SearchProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.RedirectingPage] = "False";
            this.SearchProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.FrameDocument] = "False";
            this.FilterProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.Title] = "IPVPN Router Creation";
            this.FilterProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.AbsolutePath] = "/Ordering/ROUTER/newOrder.aspx";
            this.FilterProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.PageUrl] = "http://rcorp-fil-02dev-fileadeete.sso-dev.infra.ftgroup/Ordering/ROUTER/newOrder." +
                "aspx?EditMode=Create New Router&OrderType=Addition&SitaType=IPNET&OrderStatus=Ed" +
                "it";
            this.WindowTitles.Add("IPVPN Router Creation");
            #endregion
        }
**UIOKButton:**
public HtmlInputButton UIOKButton
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUIOKButton == null))
                {
                    this.mUIOKButton = new HtmlInputButton(this);
                    #region Search Criteria
                    this.mUIOKButton.SearchProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Id] = "btnOK";
                    this.mUIOKButton.SearchProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Name] = "btnOK";
                    this.mUIOKButton.FilterProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.DisplayText] = "OK";
                    this.mUIOKButton.FilterProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Type] = "button";
                    this.mUIOKButton.FilterProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Title] = null;
                    this.mUIOKButton.FilterProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Class] = "button center";
                    this.mUIOKButton.FilterProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition] = "id=btnOK class=\"button center\" type=butt";
                    this.mUIOKButton.FilterProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.TagInstance] = "5";
                    this.mUIOKButton.WindowTitles.Add("IPVPN Router Creation");
                    #endregion
                }
                return this.mUIOKButton;
            }
        }
```

**Code tried by me(generic code) :**

```
namespace ProjectName
{
   public class CustomCaller
    {

        public static void customcallerMethod() {

            BrowserWindow broWin = new BrowserWindow();
            broWin.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name] = "Fileade";


            HtmlCustom htCus = new HtmlCustom(broWin);
            htCus.SearchProperties["TagName"] = "FRAMESET";

            HtmlFrame htFrame = new HtmlFrame(htCus);
            htFrame.SearchProperties[HtmlFrame.PropertyNames.Name] = "nav";

            HtmlDocument htDoc = new HtmlDocument(htFrame);
            htDoc.FilterProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.AbsolutePath] = "/Ordering/nav.aspx";
            Playback.Wait(2000);

            HtmlDiv htDev = new HtmlDiv(htDoc);
            htDev.SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id] = "Device";
            Mouse.Click(htDev);
            Playback.Wait(2000);
            HtmlDiv htDev1 = new HtmlDiv(htDev);
            htDev1.SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id] = "DeviceSub";

            Playback.Wait(2000);
            HtmlDiv htDev2 = new HtmlDiv(htDoc);
            htDev2.FilterProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.InnerText] = "New IP VPN";
            Mouse.Click(htDev2);
            Playback.Wait(5000);



           // UITestControl broWin1 = new UITestControl();
           // broWin1.TechnologyName = "MSAA";
            //broWin1.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name] = "IPVPN Router Creation";

// Problematic Code starts here for action to be performed on IE based popup Application---- Which does not allow me click Ok button on popup:
            BrowserWindow broWin1 = new BrowserWindow();
            broWin1.TechnologyName = "MSAA";
            broWin1.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name] = "IPVPN Router Creation";
            broWin1.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "Internet Explorer_TridentDlgFrame";

            WinWindow winWin = new WinWindow(broWin1);
            winWin.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "ThunderRT6UserControlDC";
            //winWin.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlId] = "1001";
            Playback.Wait(3000);

            //winWin.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "ThunderRT6UserControlDC";
            // Mouse.Click(winWin);

           // WinClient wClient = new WinClient(winWin);
          // wClient.WindowTitles.Add("IPVPN Router Creation");

            //UIIPVPNRouterCreationWClient.UIItemWindow
            WinWindow winWin1 = new WinWindow(winWin);
             winWin1.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "ThunderRT6ComboBox";

            //UIIPVPNRouterCreationWClient.UIItemWindow.UIIPVPNRouterCreationDocument
             HtmlDocument htDoc3 = new HtmlDocument(winWin1);
           htDoc3.FilterProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.Title] = "IPVPN Router Creation";
            //htDoc3.FilterProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.AbsolutePath] = "/Ordering/ROUTER/newOrder.aspx";

            //UIIPVPNRouterCreationWClient.UIItemWindow.UIIPVPNRouterCreationDocument.UIOKButton
           HtmlInputButton htCon = new HtmlInputButton(htDoc3);
            htCon.TechnologyName = "Web";
            htCon.SearchProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Name] = "btnOK";
            Playback.Wait(2000);
            Mouse.Click(htCon);
            Playback.Wait(3000);
```

Exception occured :

```
Test Name:  CodedUITestMethod1
Test FullName:  ProjectName.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1
Test Source:    c:\CODEUI\WorkProject\FileadePOC\FileadePOC\CodedUITest1.cs : line 38
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:49.625137
```

Result Message:

Test method ProjectName.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception: 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException: The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties. Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'Web'
ControlType:  'Document'
TagName:  'BODY'
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
Result StackTrace:
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.Engine.IScreenElement.FindAllDescendants(String bstrQueryId, Object& pvarResKeys, Int32 cResKeys, Int32 nMaxDepth)

Please help .. Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: There are many web pages where a very similar question is asked and answered. What has your research of them found? What have you tried and why were those other pages not helpful.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianHHH, But I am quite new to the CodedUI and I did research on various pages but it is not helping me out. While debugging after updating code in different ways , I am getting below error at  line Mouse.Click(htDev2);                                                                       Exception:"An exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll but was not handled in user code".So please share me links or suggest some solutions which could help me out from this issue.